# Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated using a function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table which looks like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `{{ ur_project_id }}.{{ ur_dataset_name }}.popular_domains` (
    `domains` STRING
);

INSERT INTO `{{ ur_project_id }}.{{ ur_dataset_name }}.popular_domains`
VALUES
 ('gmail.com'),
 ('yahoo.com'),
 ('hotmail.com'),
 ('aol.com'),
 ('hotmail.co.uk')
```

And then i am creating a UDF function like this one

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `{{ ur_project_id }}.{{ ur_dataset_name }}.get_email_features`(email STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<is_popular_domain INT64>
            AS
            (STRUCT(
            (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `{{ ur_project_id }}.{{ ur_dataset_name }}.popular_domains` pd WHERE pd.domains = SPLIT(email, '@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) AS is_popular_domain)));
```

And finally i am trying to pass the function created through another table containing emails

```
SELECT 
    `{{ ur_project_id }}.{{ ur_dataset_name }}.get_email_features`(email) 
FROM {{ table with emails }}
```

but unlucky i am getting :

```
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN. at
```

there is a way to correct the UDF for not falling in this error ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `STRUCT`, because you are using subqueries inside the STRUCT.

```
(STRUCT( (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1)
```

Here is another way to do the same query using functions.

This is my sample data:

[image]

This is my query using a function named `countDomains`

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION countDomains(domain STRING)
AS ((
  
select counts from (
select SPLIT(mail,'@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] as domain,count(*) as counts
FROM `eMails` where SPLIT(mail,'@')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]=domain
group by domain) as b
  
));

SELECT id,mails,countDomains(mails) as counts
from `domains` 
order by id
```

This is my output. The output are the number of domains that exist in the table `domains` and are in the table `eMAils`.

[image]